# Java - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, sql, syntax, workbench

I just want to make a simple insert into a table in my sql data base. Nonetheless I get this error eventhough I tried it in several ways. I got a table named "values" in my database "test" with a simple column for id "idValues" and a column for int values called "value". I just want to insert a simple record with 1 for ID and 1 for value (1/1). Is there maybe some problem with certain versions?

```
package jdbcdemo;
```

`import java.sql.*;`

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "rmi1337");

        Statement statement = myConn.createStatement();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO values " + "(idValues, value)" + "VALUES (1, 1)";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}


com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values(idValues, value)VALUES (1, 1)' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2607)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1480)
at jdbcdemo.Driver.main(Driver.java:22)
```

Comment: I guess `values` as a tablename isn't a good choice

Comment: As you can see, `values` is a keyword in SQL. If you're going to call your table "values" (and I suggest you don't), you would have to escape it; e.g.  `\`values\``

Comment: thank you, should have thought of that! well they could have also tolde me this when creating the table though

Comment: You also don't need to do the string concatenation at all for your `sql` variable.  It be cleaner looking at least if you removed the concatenation and made it one big string.

Answer (score 4):

Both `Values` and `value` is reserve word and thus needs escaping like

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO `values` " + "(idValues, `value`)" + " VALUES (1, 1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It misses a white space.

```
'values(idValues, value)VALUES (1, 1)'
```

should be :

```
'values(idValues, value) VALUES (1, 1)'
```

So you should write it :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO values " + "(idValues, value) " + " VALUES (1, 1)";
```

But anyway, you should not use keyword or reserved word for your metadata.
A "values" table is misleading and besides it may work according to the DBMS used and also the OS used.

In this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) presenting how MySQL handle the case sensitivity, you can read :

> This means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

In this [other link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) you can get information about MySQL reserved keys.